# Sequelize hasOne through another table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following three models

**User**

```
user_id
user_email
```

**Group**

```
group_id
group_name
```

**GroupUser**

```
group_user_id
user_id
group_id
```

How can I get group details(if it mapped with user ) while fetch User data ?
Is there any Sequelize hasOne association through another table ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is currently no direct way in sequelize for what you are asking

ref https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3845

but you can do

```
Group.belongsTo(GroupUser)
User.belongsTo(GroupUser)
GroupUser.hasOne(Group)
GroupUser.hasOne(User)
```

and do nested include (but this is not very efficient)

```
User.findAll({include : [{model:GroupUser, include :[{model : Group}]}]})
```

Comment: Thanks bro , let me try your solution.